# How to pass one row of data from controller to view , not as IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to send data from controller to view like

```
EMP e =(EMP) db.EMPs.Where(n => n.id == j);
return View(e);
```

Here `EMP` is `Model` object.
The Error is

> Unable to cast object of type System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[WebApplication1.Models.EMP] to type WebApplication1.Models.EMP

Note : I cant use `IEnumerable<Model>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to do that:

```
// this way would throw exception if no result was found or more than 1 result
EMP e =(EMP) db.EMPs.Single(n => n.id == j);

// if no result was found, return null
EMP e =(EMP) db.EMPs.SingleOrDefault(n => n.id == j);

// if no result was found, throw exception. 
// if there are more than 1 result, return the first item
EMP e =(EMP) db.EMPs.First(n => n.id == j);

// if no result was found, return null. 
// if there are more than 1 result, return the first item
EMP e =(EMP) db.EMPs.FirstOrDefault(n => n.id == j);

// cast to list 
List<EMP> e =(EMP) db.EMPs.Where(n => n.id == j).ToList();
// then, select the first item via index:
return View(e[0]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Just replace the `Where` with `FirstOrDefault` to returns the first element of the sequence:

```
EMP e = (EMP) db.EMPs.FirstOrDefault(n => n.id == j);
```

Comment: Additional note: Always check the return value of `FirstOrDefault` because it also can return `null` in case the predicate did not match.